# Query documents, update it and return it back to MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, insert-update, database

In my MongoDB 3.2 based application I want to perform the documents processing. In order to avoid the repeated processing on the same document I want to update its flag and update this document in the database.

The possible approach is:

1. Query the data: `FindIterable<Document> documents = db.collection.find(query);`.
2. Perform some business logic on these documents.
3. Iterate over the `documents`, update each document and store it in a new collection.
4. Push the new collection to the database with `db.collection.updateMany();`.

Theoretically, this approach should work but I'm not sure that it is the optimal scenario.

Is there any way in MongoDB Java API to perform the followings two operations:

1. to query documents (to get them from the DB and to pass to the separate method);
2. to update them and then store the updated version in DB;

in a more elegant way comparing to the proposed above approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can update document inplace using [update](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.update/):

```
db.collection.update(
    {query},
    {update},
    {multi:true}
);
```

It will iterate over all documents in the collection which match the `query` and updated fields specified in the `update`.

**EDIT:**

To apply *some business logic* to individual documents you can iterate over matching documents as following:

```
db.collection.find({query}).forEach(
    function (doc) {
        // your logic business
        if (doc.question == "Great Question of Life") {
            doc.answer = 42;
        }
        db.collection.save(doc);
    }
)
```

Comment: And what if besides the need to update these documents I also want to get them for the further proceeding? In other words, I want to get the documents, to use them, to mark them as proceeded and only after that to return them to the database.

Comment: Then question is too broad indeed.

Comment: I tried to narrow and specify the question. Please, have a look on an updated version.

Comment: Ok, I have updated the answer with one more example, but there are much more ways to deal with documents in mongodb. You may need to lear what the db is capable of, or hire a consultant to work out the best approach for **your** case. Your 1..4/1..2 points are applicable to any persistent storage and are not mongodb specific.